# Chrome on android video element unable to play from mediaRecorder blob data url

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, video, mediarecorder

**Preface**

I am using the webRTC mediaRecorder api to record video on a mobile web app. The video data is recording and can be downloaded and played in a video player app on the device.

**Problem**

The problem is that the recorded data blob array is unable to playback on the mobile device in chrome even on the latest release when using:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(); or window.webkitURL.createObjectURL()
```

I have found this document stating that there is a bug in chrome on android. [Chrome Bug Report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253465)

I did find some documentation from google that even highlights the bug here:
[Google devs mediaRecorder docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder?hl=en)

**Question**

Has anyone found a workaround to playback recorded media in a video element using google chrome on android?

**Solutions Tested and Failed**

test 1: Using the blob window url as the src on the video element

```
<video src="[example blob url]>
```

test 2: Using the blob window url as the source on the video element

```
<video>
    <source type="video/webm" src="[example blob url]">
```

test 3: Convert the mediaRecorder blob array to a dataURI using the FileReader api.

```
function getVideoDataUri(callBackFn) 
{ 
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    var fileMime = 'video/webm'; 
    var blob = new Blob(this.blobs, {type: fileMime}); 
    reader.onload = function(e) 
    {  
        if(typeof callBackFn === 'function') 
        { 
            callBackFn(reader.result); 
        } 
    }; 
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
} 

function callBack(dataUri) 
{ 
    /* do something with data */ 
    console.log(dataUri); 
} 

getVideoDataUri(callBack);
```

Comment: Did anyone come up with any workaround for this yet?

Comment: Yes. Test 3 will solve the problem. I am using it currently. I can send production code if you need it.

Comment: Sending production code would be appreciated. I tried the Test 3, same thing, no luck. My machine is on Android 4.4 (API 19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though test 3 is the answer. it works but the video doesn't autoplay until clicked. I am playing back recorded media in a video element.

Comment: I need it autoplay, any luck yet?

Comment: No. On mobile they have blocked autoplaying due to data limits. Even by spoofing events it still refuses.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment due to my rep but I thought you would like to now It will be fixed soon, see [chrome bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253465).

Thanks for sharing your test 3, saved my day!